# Assign minimum data value to new variable in R - Nested for loop

Tags: r, date, datetime, nested-loops

**Background:**

**1st Table:**

| ID | Pending | New | Approved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | NA | NA | 2021-05-20 |
| 002 | NA | NA | 2021-05-20 |
| 003 | NA | NA | 2021-05-20 |
| 004 | NA | NA | 2021-05-20 |

**2nd Table:**

| ID | date |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 2021-04-30 |
| 002 | 2021-04-30 |
| 003 | 2021-04-30 |
| 004 | 2021-04-30 |

**What I want:** I want to write a nested for loop where R is able to find the smallest date value in table two and attach it to the variable "New" in table 1.

**My current code looks like this:**

```
for(i in 1:nrow(merged_final)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(merged_final)){
    if(is.na(merged_final$New[j]))
      merged_final[merged_final$New[i] == min(query1.1$Coach340BClaimsID == query1.1$Coach340BClaimsID[j])]
  }
}
```

This does not seem to be working. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two common operations: (a) find the smallest value by group, and (b) join two data sets. You don't need a loop, much less a nested loop.

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
# find min vals by group
min_val = data2 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(which.min(date)) %>%
  rename(New2 = date)   ## rename the column to be ready to merge

# join to original data
data1 = data1 %>%
  left_join(min_val, by = "ID") %>%
  mutate(New = coalesce(New, New2))
```

Comment: the issue is I only want to input dates where New = NA so dropping the "New" column doesn't work. I apologize, I should have mentioned that in the first original post

Comment: Making edits to address that...